# Total distance of a vehicle

Tags: calculus

I need help with a calculus problem please.

> A vehicle moves horizontally along the $x$ axis (in meters). Its
>   velocity is represented by the function  $v(t) = 6 e^{-2t/5} \cos(5t)$
>   m/s and its initial position is $s(0) = 3$ m. A positive velocity
>   indicates displacement towards the right.
>
> Determine its final position as well as its total distance travelled.

I've already integrated $v(t)$ to find the equation of $s(t)$,

\begin{align}
  v(t) &= 6e^{-2t/5}\cos(5t)\\[0.8em]
  s(t) &= \int v(t) dt \\[0.8em]
  &= \frac{-30e^5\left(2\cdot \cos(5t) - 25\cdot \sin(5t)\right)}{629} + C\\[0.8em]
  s(0) &= 3\\[0.8em]
  3 &= \frac{-30e^5\left(2\cdot \cos(5 \cdot 0) - 25\cdot \sin(5 \cdot 0)\right)}{629} + C\\[0.8em]
  C &= \frac{1947}{629}\\[0.8em]
  s(t) &= \frac{-30e^5\left(2\cdot \cos(5 t) - 25\cdot \sin(5 t)\right)}{629} + \frac{1947}{629}\
 \end{align}

I also found the final position of the vehicle to be $\lim_{t \to\infty^+} s(t) = \frac{1947}{629} = 3.0953\ $, because thats the horizontal asymptote of $s(t)$,

But I have no idea how to find the total distance travelled by the vehicle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: total distance should be integrating $|v(t)|$ over the given time interval.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MathNewbie. Could you explain why that would give the the total distance ?

Comment: When $v(t)$ is negative, you're moving left. So we need to take account of that distance too. When you're just integrating $v(t)$, it represents the total displacement, which is different from total distance.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @MathNewbie , thanks ! And lastly, this intergral would be $\int_{0}^{\infty} |v(t)|dt$ ?

Comment: Sure no problem. Yeah, it'll be $\int_0^{^{\infty}} |v(t)|dt$.

Comment: @MathNewbie, So I just did $\int_{0}^{\infty} |v(t)|dt = 0.095$, but that gives me the same answer as $3.0953 - 3 = 0.095$ which is the total displacement of the vehicle. Am I a making a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: Perhaps you can put your work above, but looking at $\int_0^{\infty}v(t)dt$, it shouldn't be the same as $\int_0^{\infty}|v(t)|dt$ since the cosine term can be negative in $v(t)$.

Comment: @MathNewbie, ok so I just put how I found the final position of the vehicle. Then to find the total displacement, I did $position_{final} - position_{initial}$ and that seems to be the same as the total distance ($ \int_{0}^{\infty} |v(t)| dt$)